# Compiling Python to WebAssembly

Tags: python, emscripten, webassembly

I have read that it is possible to convert Python 2.7 code to Web Assembly, but I cannot find a definitive guide on how to to so.

So far I have compiled a C program to Web Assembly using Emscripten and all its necessary components, so I know it is working (guide used: http://webassembly.org/getting-started/developers-guide/)

What are the steps I must take in order to do this on an Ubuntu machine? Do I have to convert the python code to LLVM bitcode then compile it using Emscripten? If so, how would I achieve this?

Comment: @guettli https://github.com/pypyjs/pypyjs/issues/145

Comment: Check out `pyodide`: https://hacks.mozilla.org/2019/04/pyodide-bringing-the-scientific-python-stack-to-the-browser

Comment: Pyodide brings the Python runtime to the browser via WebAssembly: https://github.com/iodide-project/pyodide

Answer (score 190, accepted):

## WebAssembly vs asm.js

First, let's take a look how, in principle, *WebAssembly* is different from *asm.js*, and whether there's potential to reuse existing knowledge and tooling. The following gives pretty good overview:

- [Why create a new standard when there is already asm.js?](http://webassembly.org/docs/faq/#why-create-a-new-standard-when-there-is-already-asmjs)
- [What is the difference between asm.js and web assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31502563/2072035)
- [Why WebAssembly is Faster Than asm.js](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2017/03/why-webassembly-is-faster-than-asm-js/)

Let's recapitulate, WebAssembly (MVP, as there's more on [its roadmap](https://github.com/WebAssembly/design/blob/master/FutureFeatures.md), roughly):

- is a binary format of AST with static typing, which can be executed by existing JavaScript engines (and thus JIT-able or compiled AOT),
- it's 10-20% more compact (gzipped comparison) and an order of magnitude faster to parse than JavaScript,
- it can express more low-level operation that won't fit into JavaScript syntax, read asm.js (e.g. 64-bit integers, special CPU instructions, SIMD, etc)
- is convertible (to some extent) to/from asm.js.

Thus, currently WebAssembly is an iteration on asm.js and targets only C/C++ (and similar languages).

## Python on the Web

It doesn't look like GC is the only thing that stops Python code from targeting WebAssembly/asm.js. Both represent low-level statically typed code, in which Python code can't (realistically) be represented. As current toolchain of WebAssembly/asm.js is based on LLVM, a language that can be easily compiled to LLVM IR can be converted to WebAssembly/asm.js. But alas, Python is too dynamic to fit into it as well, as proven by [Unladen Swallow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPython#Unladen_Swallow) and [several attempts](http://rpython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#could-we-use-llvm) of PyPy.

This asm.js presentation has [slides about the state of dynamic languages](http://kripken.github.io/mloc_emscripten_talk/). What it means is that currently it's only possible to compile whole VM (language implementation in C/C++) to WebAssembly/asm.js and interpret (with JIT where possible) original sources. For Python there're several existing projects:

1. PyPy: [PyPy.js](https://github.com/pypyjs/pypyjs) (author's [talk at PyCon](https://youtu.be/PiBfOFqDIAI)). Here's [release repo](https://github.com/pypyjs/pypyjs-release). Main JS file, `pypyjs.vm.js`, is 13 MB (2MB after `gzip -6`) + Python stdlib + other stuff.
2. CPython: [pyodide](https://github.com/iodide-project/pyodide), [EmPython](https://github.com/aidanhs/empython), [CPython-Emscripten](https://github.com/dgym/cpython-emscripten), [EmCPython](https://github.com/PeachPy/EmCPython), etc. `empython.js` is 5.8 MB (2.1 MB after `gzip -6`), no stdlib.
3. Micropython: [this fork](https://github.com/matthewelse/micropython/tree/emscripten/emscripten).

   There was no built JS file there, so I was able to build it with [`trzeci/emscripten/`](https://hub.docker.com/r/trzeci/emscripten/), a ready-made Emscripten toolchain. Something like:

   ```
    git clone https://github.com/matthewelse/micropython.git
    cd micropython
    docker run --rm -it -v $(pwd):/src trzeci/emscripten bash
    apt-get update && apt-get install -y python3
    cd emscripten
    make -j
    # to run REPL: npm install && nodejs server.js
   ```

   It produces `micropython.js` of 1.1 MB (225 KB after `gzip -d`). The latter is already something to consider, if you need only very compliant implementation without stdlib.

   To produce WebAssembly build you can change line 13 of the `Makefile` to

   ```
    CC = emcc -s RESERVED_FUNCTION_POINTERS=20 -s WASM=1
   ```

   Then `make -j` produces:

   ```
    113 KB micropython.js
    240 KB micropython.wasm
   ```

   You can look at HTML output of `emcc hello.c -s WASM=1 -o hello.html`, to see how to use these files.

   This way you can also potentially build PyPy and CPython in WebAssembly to interpret your Python application in a compliant browser.

Another potentially interesting thing here is [Nuitka](http://nuitka.net/), a Python to C++ compiler. Potentially it can be possible to build your Python app to C++ and then compile it along with CPython with Emscripten. But practically I've no idea how to do it.

## Solutions

For the time being, if you're building a conventional web site or web app where download several-megabyte JS file is barely an option, take a look at Python-to-JavaScript transpilers (e.g. [Transcrypt](https://github.com/qquick/Transcrypt)) or JavaScript Python implementations (e.g. [Brython](https://github.com/brython-dev/brython)). Or try your luck with others from [list of languages that compile to JavaScript](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffeescript/wiki/List-of-languages-that-compile-to-JS#python).

Otherwise, if download size is not an issue, and you're ready to tackle a lot of rough edges, choose between the three above.

## Q3 2020 update

1. JavaScript port [was integrated](https://github.com/micropython/micropython/commit/7d675f3a) into MicroPython. It lives in
   [ports/javascript](https://github.com/micropython/micropython/tree/master/ports/javascript).
2. The port is available as a npm package called [MicroPython.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/micropython).
   You can try it out in [RunKit](https://runkit.com/npm/micropython).
3. There's an actively developed Python implementation in Rust, called
   [RustPython](https://github.com/RustPython/RustPython). Because Rust officially supports [WebAssembly as
   compile target](https://www.rust-lang.org/what/wasm), no surprise there's [demo link](https://rustpython.github.io/demo/) right in the
   top of the readme. Though, it's early. Their disclaimer follows.

   > RustPython is in a development phase and should not be used in
   > production or a fault intolerant setting.
   >
   > Our current build supports only a subset of Python syntax.

## Q1 2023 update

Python 3.11 [recognises two WebAssembly "platforms"](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/intro.html#webassembly-platforms) in its documentation and documents its API availability on them among other platforms like Linux and Unix (see [this PR](https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/95452) for more details) and also recommends Pyodide (from Mozilla) and another port, PyScript (from Anaconda), based on it:

> The [WebAssembly](https://webassembly.org/) platforms `wasm32-emscripten`
> ([Emscripten](https://emscripten.org/)) and `wasm32-wasi` ([WASI](https://wasi.dev/)) provide a subset
> of POSIX APIs. WebAssembly runtimes and browsers are sandboxed and
> have limited access to the host and external resources. Any Python
> standard library module that uses processes, threading, networking,
> signals, or other forms of inter-process communication (IPC), is
> either not available or may not work as on other Unix-like systems.
>
> [...]
>
> For Python in the browser, users should consider [Pyodide](https://pyodide.org/) or
> [PyScript](https://pyscript.net/). PyScript is built on top of Pyodide, which itself is built
> on top of CPython and Emscripten. Pyodide provides access to
> browsers’ JavaScript and DOM APIs as well as limited networking
> capabilities with JavaScript’s XMLHttpRequest and Fetch APIs.

Comment: Those .js and .wasm sizes aren't really fair. Stream compression is well supported and could be used to reduce the size of both. How big are the same files, gzipped? Other than that, good answer.

Comment: So wanted to add that in 2020, it seems pyodide is the closest thing OP is looking for. It is the Python runtime in web assembly (I would assume the put C and then Python into wasm). It supports multiple libraries as well. Also, seems easy enough to use.

Comment: so I can't use Pyodide to create a WebApp with WebAssembly? I would like to use Flask as a back-end

Comment: whats the use of just another python interpreter written in rust

Comment: @HaMAD The use is due to Rust having good support for compiling to WASM, which means you could potentially compile the Rust port of Python to WASM. You could compile a C program to WASM as well, but I'm not sure how nice it is to get that working.

Answer (score 10):

In short: There are transpilers, but you can't automatically convert any arbitrary Python to Web Assembly, and I doubt you will be able to for a long time to come.  Although theoretically the languages are equally powerful, and manual translation is always possible, Python allows for some data structures and expressive modes that requires a very smart inter-language compiler (or transpiler) [see below].  A workaround might be Python to C to Web Assembly since python-to-C technology is moderately mature, but that isn't generally going to work either since Python-to-C is also fragile (see below).

WebAssembly is specifically targeted to C-like languages as you can see at http://webassembly.org/docs/high-level-goals/

Translating from Python to C can be done with tools like PyPy, which has been under development for a long time, but which still does not work for arbitrary Python code.  There are several reasons for this:

1. Python has some very handy, abstract and nice data structures, but they are hard to translate into static code.
2. Python depends on dynamic garbage collection.
3. Most Python code depends heavily on various libraries, each of which has it's own quirks and issues (such as being written in C, or even assembler).

If you look more carefully into why Python-to-C (or Python to C++) has been so tricky you can see the detailed reasons behind this terse answer, but I think that's outside the scope of your question.

Answer (score 3):

This won't be possible until web assembly implements garbage collection. You can follow progress here: https://github.com/WebAssembly/proposals/issues/16

Comment: Not necessarily. You can implement GC -- and especially reference counting, as it's used by Python IIRC -- on top of Wasm. In principle, you should be able to take CPython and compile it to Wasm using Emscripten.

Comment: My take from OP was that they wanted to use existing tools -- implementing cpython GC on top of wasm sounds like a project in itself

Comment: You shouldn't have to do anything extra, just get CPython to compile. It already contains the RC implementation, AFAICT.

Comment: Both chrome and firefox shipped that this month. [Here](https://v8.dev/blog/wasm-gc-porting) they explain why (while not strictly required) it's very much the real™ way forward.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing comes into my mind is PyPy and rpython, then I found

https://github.com/soIu/rpython

We cannot turn arbitrary python code into rpython. However, if you need an alternative language rather than rust or AssemblyScript, rpython might be a direction.

Thus, I can use python/js/rust with wasm as a sandbox, and coding in a very pythonic language such as rpython. At least I don't need to worry about over flow of integer.

Answer (score 0):

Python is too dynamic for WASM, in result you can get only interpreter implemented in WASM but not your code was compiled.

In the other way, you can try to use Python as a tooling language, and write your own model compiler into WASM. I mean not source-to-WASM compiling, but compiler which transforms the model of your application into WASM or some other low-level language say Rust or C++.

Such a model can be implemented as a data structure combined from objects that describes parts of your application: modules, classes, API interfaces, GUI elements etc. Such objects must have code generationg methods which "knows" how to write its state and behaviour into fragments of low-level code.

Next, you can manually build your application by combining such generated code fragments into project can be built with WASM-enabled compiler or just WAT files.