# Python in browser with WebAssembly without recompilation

Tags: python, webassembly, emscripten

I've looked at [Compiling Python to WebAssembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44761748/compiling-python-to-webassembly), and its various answers, various projects (EmPython, [EmCPython](https://github.com/PeachPy/EmCPython), [cpython-emscripten](https://github.com/dgym/cpython-emscripten), Pyodide, etc.) but most of the time, it requires recompilation or using Docker, etc.

Is there a way to use Python in the browser (with WebAssembly), such that it works like this:

- You simply put `foo.js`, `foo.wasm`, `index.html`, or similar ready-to-use files in a directory
- **You put a `main.py` file in the directory**, that the WebAssembly Python interepreter automatically starts when we open `index.html` in the browser, and **Python stdout is directly displayed in the browser**
- You can import standard Python modules by simply adding the .py files along `main.py`

Example:

```
pythoninbrowser.js
pythoninbrowser.wasm
index.html
main.py    --> containing "import bs4"
bs4/
    __init__.py
    ...all the rest of the BeautifulSoup module...
```

See also [this issue](https://github.com/iodide-project/pyodide/issues/678).